# Django Class Based Views Login

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert my `function based view` into a `class based view` in `Django`. The functionality of the view is to display a homepage as well as a login/logout form/button. [image]

Basically, if the user is logged in, the logout button will be displayed underneath `Account` and if the user is already logged out, a `login` form will be displayed instead. So it works for my function based view:

`views.py`

```
def _get_login_form(request):
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)

    return form

@csrf_protect
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = forms.Form(request.POST or None)
        if 'logout-button' in request.POST and form.is_valid():
            logout(request)
            form = _get_login_form(request)
    else:
        form = _get_login_form(request)

    info = {
        'company_name' : 'Purpose VC',
        'form': form,
        'lorem': '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
 Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'''
    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', info)
```

But I am having trouble with the `Class based View`. This is what I have so far:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['company_name'] = 'Purpose VC'
        context['lorem'] = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
 Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'''
        context['form'] = kwargs['form']
        return context

    def get(self, request):
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
        return self.get_context_data(self, form)

    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if 'logout-button' in request.POST and form.is_valid():
                logout(request)
                form = self._get_login_form(request)
        else:
            form = self._get_login_form(request)

        return self.get_context_data(self, form)

    def _get_login_form(self, request):
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.POST and form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)

        return form
```

I am having trouble passing in the corresponding form based on if the user is authenticated or not. The specific error I get is `context['form'] = kwargs['form']
KeyError: 'form'`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
context['form'] = self.kwargs.get('form')
```

Comment: Okay that seemed to work. Now I think I need to implement a `get` function because the form isn't displaying.

Comment: Can you tell me what is  form = forms.Form(request.POST or None) use of this line and how it is working?

Comment: Sorry that is an unnecessary line of code. I have edited the code above.

Comment: So I think I needed to add a `get` function so that we can handle the get `request.` But now I get the error `TypeError: get_context_data() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`. I thought `**kwargs` can take as many args as it wants.

Comment: remove 'self'  from 'parameter in method 

return self.get_context_data(self, form)

Comment: follow templateview structure https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/