# How to block user login with certain status in Django

Tags: python, django, django-login

I'm using Django 1.11 and views based on classes.
My user model is customized and it has a `status` field where it has "enabled, blocked and disabled". I'd like to know how I can only allow users to log in and the others are barred.

Thanks!

Comment: Every time a `User` tries to login check their `status` is enabled as well after you `authenticate` their username and password.

Comment: How do I do this using class-based views?

Comment: Show some of your code i.e. your view  and models. and btw you can do all the checking where you are performing the `authentication` .

Comment: Well, I'm using the default django login. And the only thing I need is every time the user is logged in to be verified if it is "enabled". This status is an enum in the user model. I thought about overwriting the authentication, but I do not know how, or if there is a simpler and more correct way.
Follow account app:
https://github.com/leonardfreitas/easyos_api/tree/master/accounts

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286026/django-class-based-views-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override default form,

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class AuthenticationFormWithChekUsersStatus(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.status == 'enabled':
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                ("Your account has disabled."),
                code='inactive',
            )
```

the docs: [AuthenticationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm)

And in your urls, it can be like:

```
from forms import AuthenticationFormWithChekUsersStatus

url(
    r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
        authentication_form=AuthenticationFormWithChekUsersStatus
    )
)
```

more details: [all-authentication-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to check if user `status` is `enabled`

```
from django.views.generic import View

class LoginView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.status == 'enabled': # checking if user is "enabled"
                login(request, user)

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/form')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Disabled user.")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

        return render(request, "index.html")
```